# Access ipod music library and display soundlist with length

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification, mpmediapickercontroller

I am trying access iPod music library and after that creating a local notification when my application is in background. I want to play the selected sound in local notification. My problem is Apple allow only those files which are less then 30sec. in length.

So is there any way to get list of only those sound which are less then 30sec length?

If I get this list then I need to copy the selected media file in my resource bundle.
Then I can paas it to my local notification. until and unless if there is any way to paas a media item directly to local notification.

Thanks to all for helping..

Comment: You can't write to your app bundle, last I checked.

Comment: http://blog.tapsquare.com/post/803301658/ipod-library-access This link is saying that it is possible but not getting anything how to achive

Comment: You still can't write to your app bundle, since that would break the code signature (and is pretty bad practice anyway). You can write to the Library, Documents, and temp directories (and there are plenty of examples of how to get the paths to these), but it's unclear if you can play these sounds from notifications (you could try a path like `../Library/Application Support/MyApp/MySound.mp4` or whatever, but it's not guaranteed to work reliably). Note that the Documents directory is "traditional" but is exposed by iTunes file sharing; you probably want something in Library.

Comment: Hello @TC can you plz move your comment to answer so i can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want items under "music" only (not podcasts or ringtones), something like this should work:

```
MPMediaQuery * query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
NSArray * items = [query items];
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:
   ^(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings){
     MPMediaItem * item = evaluatedObject;
     NSNumber * duration = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
     return [duration doubleValue] < 30;
   }];
NSArray * filteredItems = [items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Unfortunately `MPMediaPropertyPredicate` doesn't let us filter by "duration less than 30 seconds" (the comparison types are "EqualTo" and "Contains"), so we do it manually above.

Then you need to export the desired track using `AVAssetExportSession`. You probably need to convert it to one of the supported formats in the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6). I also suggest using a fixed filename so it's easier to keep track of the files you've created.

Finally, you can't write to your app bundle since this invalidates the code signature (apparently you used to be able to; perhaps the signature is only checked at install time). However, you *might* be able to use a relative path like `../Library/Application Support/MyApp/MySound.mp4`.

**Note that this is not guaranteed to work and might fail app review!** In particular,

- There's no guarantee that the path will start with `../Library`. An algorithm for generating relative paths is beyond the scope of this answer. (An absolute path probably won't work since it doesn't work with `-[NSString stringByAppendingPathComponent:]`.)
- There's no guarantee that `UILocalNotification.soundName` will accept a path; the documentation simply says it accepts a "filename (including extension) of a sound resource in the application’s main bundle".